# Convering yyyy-mm-dd to unix timestamp in array and put it back at the same position after converted it. [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm very new at javascript and highstock.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    I want to put datetime into Highstock and realized that it accepted just only Unix time stamp.
However, my datetime data is in yyyy-mm-dd format how can I convert datetime data in object and put it back to the same position?

My data is

object =

a: [ '2014-04-12'(string), 120],

b: [ '2013-02-12', 300],

c: [ '2013-03-15', 300]

But, there are 1000 data in my object
I would be grateful if you could help me with this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: this is not correct object notation

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. The data is actually like this
a:['2014-04-12(string), 120']
b:['2013-02-12,300']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object actually looks like this:

```
object = {
 a: [ '2014-04-12', 120],
 b: [ '2013-02-12', 300],
 c: [ '2013-03-15', 300]
}
```

you can do this:

```
for(var k in object) {
   object[k][0] = new Date(object[k][0]).getTime()
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c5hpe0qq/1/